# Consider all numbers, from two-digit up to 10-digit, written only with digits 1, 2, 3, 5, 7. Identify those that are perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, digits

> Consider all numbers, from two-digit up to 10-digit, written only with digits 1, 2, 3, 5, 7. Identify those that are perfect squares

I got this problem but don't know how to solve it. This is what I did so far.

For example: 121 is one such number, since it uses only digits 1 and 2 and it is a perfect square.

```
list = Flatten[Table[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, i], {i, 2, 10}], 1];
list2 = Table[FromDigits[list[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[list]}];
Select[list2, IntegerQ[Sqrt[#]] &]
```

Comment: First thing: you want `Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {i}]` instead if you want to list *only* tuples of length `i`.

Answer (score 7):

OP's method used with smaller number of digits:

```
n = 9;
(list = Flatten[Table[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, i], {i, 2, n}], 1];
   list2 = Table[FromDigits[list[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[list]}];
   result0 = Select[list2, IntegerQ[Sqrt[#]] &];) //  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 359.991
> ```

An alternative approach:

```
result1 = Select[FreeQ[0 | 6 | 8 | 9] @* IntegerDigits]@ 
     (Range[3, Ceiling[N @ Sqrt[FromDigits[ConstantArray[7, n]]]]]^2); // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.091785
> ```

```
result0 == result1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

We get the result for 10 digits in a fraction of a second:

```
result10digits = Select[FreeQ[0 | 6 | 8 | 9] @* IntegerDigits]@
     (Range[3, Ceiling[N@Sqrt[FromDigits[ConstantArray[7, 10]]]]]^2); //  
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.2668
> ```

```
Length @ result10digits
```

> ```
> 714
> ```

Comment: Nitpick: the digit `4` isn't allowed in the desired numbers.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, I went with the first line in the first code block in OP.